# Using AutoFixture to create MockFileSystem and its corresponding types

Tags: c#, autofixture

I'm using AutoFixture to test some code that uses `System.IO.Abstractions.IFileSystem`.

I also have some code that uses `IFileInfo` and `IDirectoryInfo`. When I create my AutoFixture `Fixture` object, I need to accomplish a couple of things:

1. I need all `IFileSystem` parameters to be automatically given a frozen (singleton) instance of `MockFileSystem`.
2. All `IFileInfo` instances need to originate from `MockFileSystem` via `MockFileSystem.FileInfo.FromFileName()` somehow. If there's a way to take an existing `IFileInfo` that AutoFixture created and replace it, I can use the `FullName` property to pass to MockFileSystem so that it's connected to that instance.
3. Similar to the previous point, I need `IDirectoryInfo` instances to originate from `MockFileSystem`.

I personally find the AutoFixture customization system very confusing and lacks proper documentation. There's pieces of information out there but I'm not sure how to accomplish my goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I struggled through solving my own problem, I eventually came up with this class:

```cs
public class MockFileSystemSpecimenBuilder : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        var fs = new MockFileSystem();
        fixture.Inject(fs);

        fixture.Customize<IFileInfo>(x => x.FromFactory(() =>
        {
            var name = $"MockFile-{fixture.Create<string>()}";
            return fs.CurrentDirectory().File(name);
        }));

        fixture.Customize<IDirectoryInfo>(x => x.FromFactory(() =>
        {
            var name = $"MockDirectory-{fixture.Create<string>()}";
            return fs.CurrentDirectory().SubDirectory(name);
        }));
    }
}
```

I add it to my `Fixture` class after its created in my factory method:

```cs
public static Fixture Create()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture
    {
        OmitAutoProperties = true
    };

    fixture
        .Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization {ConfigureMembers = true})
        .Customize(new MockFileSystemSpecimenBuilder());

    return fixture;
}
```

One thing I really enjoy about this solution is that I do not need to explicitly `Freeze()` the `IFileSystem` type anymore. The mock filesystem is intrinsic to this fixture so I always get correct file system behavior. This ends up being less error prone and more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

I think most of the problems you've described are not really AutoFixture issues, but rather design issues. AutoFixture can help build stuff for you but it doesn't generate behavior, those tasks are usually delegated to the mocking frameworks.

In your case, since you already use the fakes provided by `System.IO.Abstractions`, all you need to do is instruct AutoFixture to relay the requests for `IFileSystem` to `MockFileSystem`.

```cs
fixture.Customizations.Add(new TypeRelay(typeof(IFileSystem), typeof(MockFileSystem)));
```

Now when you want to resolve the same `IFileSystem` instance you can instead freeze the `MockFileSystem` instance.

Instructing `MockFileSystem` to return expected data is a bit trickier but not impossible. Since `MockFileSystem` accepts file data information during construction only, it means that you'll need to freeze/inject/register the file data dictionary before you create your first `MockFileSystem` instance.

Your options mainly are to either inject the data `fixture.Inject<IDictionary<string, MockFileData>>(myFileData)` or register a delegate that can generate your data `fixture.Register<IDictionary<string, MockFileData>>(() => GenerateFileData())`.

There is the more advanced option to make a custom specimen builder to generate the paths and the file data, but that would require for you to provide the algorithm that would generate this test data.